# Bootstrap table with no outer borders

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm stuck with this using Bootstrap 3.

In my html page there is a table class="table bordeless table1"> I need to remove the top, left, and right outer borders from. Tried a few solutions to no avail. What CSS do I need to apply? It seems as if only the default Bootstrap styling was applied.

Here's the Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/gTK21tStoQn5hTUy4peZ?p=preview

HTML:

```
<section id='top5'>
    <div class='container table1'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-12 settings'>
                <h4><i class="fa fa-user fa-2x"></i>Настройки > Профиль организации > X5 Retail Group</h4>
                <h4><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>Добавить пользователя</h4>
                <br>
                <table class="table bordeless table1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class='notop' width="28%">ФИО, должность</th>
                            <th width="3%">Контактное лицо</th>
                            <th width="3%">Телефон</th>
                            <th width="10%">E-mail</th>
                            <th width="10%">Уровень доступа</th>
                            <th width="8%">Инженерные системы</th>
                            <th width="5%">Объекты</th>
                            <th width="5%">Изменить</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Иванов Иван Иванович, Технический директор</td>
                            <td class="vert-align"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></td>
                            <td>8-916-234-54-21</td>
                            <td>contact@company.ru</td>
                            <td>Администратор</td>
                            <td class="vert-align"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></td>
                            <td class="vert-align"><i class="fa fa-industry"></td>
                            <td class="vert-align"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Петров Пётр Петрович, Главный инженер</td>
                            <td class="vert-align"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></td>
                            <td>8-916-234-54-21</td>
                            <td>contact@company.ru</td>
                            <td>Мониторинг</td>
                            <td class="vert-align"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></td>
                            <td class="vert-align"><i class="fa fa-industry"></td>
                            <td class="vert-align"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Сидоров Сидор Сидорович, Сервисный инженер</td>
                            <td class="vert-align"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></td>
                            <td>8-916-234-54-21</td>
                            <td>contact@company.ru</td>
                            <td>Инжиниринг</td>
                            <td class="vert-align"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></td>
                            <td class="vert-align"><i class="fa fa-industry"></td>
                            <td class="vert-align"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3):

trick is

```
border-style: hidden
```

see my test result,

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems simple....as you have changed the class (per the comments below) for the table.

Add this:

```
table.table.bordeless.mytable {
    border-bottom: */ your styles here */
}
```

Comment: I just notices I added the same class .table1 to the .container and to the actual table .table bordeless table1. Fixed that by giving the .container and the table different class names. However That only removed the border around the container.

Comment: The container class I changed to .container tables and the actual table class to. table borderless table1. If I were to remove the top border using these class name I believe the styling would look like .table.bordeless.table1 {
 border-top: none;
}

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of BootStrap you're using, there's a typo in your class that might be causing you issues.:

```
<table class="table bordeless table1">
```

Should be:

```
<table class="table borderless table1">
```

Comment: Thanks you. Missed that. To my understanding that would produce a standard Bootstrap borderless table.  I need to remove only 3 particular borders. Should I apply the .table-bordered class instead?

Answer (score 0):

just try to change your table tag to be as the following:

```
<table border="0">
</table>
```